# Spring Boot + Spring Cloud Config - How to add more profiles from the Git external configuration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have this configuration in a spring boot application:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  profiles:
    active: ${ENVIRONMENT}
  cloud:
    config:
     uri: http://localhost:8888
```

My config server reads the following files:

**my-app-dev.yaml**

```
prop: dev property
```

**my-app-pro.yaml**

```
prop: pro property.
```

I launch the spring boot app setting `-DENVIRONMENT=dev`, loading correctly the dev external Git properties.

When I inject the Environment in let's say a controller and do `env.getActiveProfiles()` I get "dev" as expected.

I would like to add more profiles from the git configuration. For instance:

**my-app-dev.yaml**

```
prop: dev property
spring:
  active:
    profiles: dev,business1
```

**my-app-pro.yaml**

```
prop: dev property
spring:
  active:
    profiles: pro,business2
```

So that `env.getActiveProfiles()` returns `["dev","business1"]`. However what it returns is the initial `"dev"`.

How could this be done?

**UPDATE:**

As suggested by Dave Syer I tried using `spring.profiles.include` in the Git files but the new profiles aren't added to the Environment:

**my-app-dev.yaml**

```
prop: dev property
spring:
  profiles:
    include: business1
```

**my-app-pro.yaml**

```
prop: dev property
spring:
  profiles:
    include: business2
```

`environment.getActiveProfiles() ---> "dev"`

Comment: Did you try `spring.profiles.include` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-adding-active-profiles)?

Comment: @DaveSyer, I just tried it but the injected `Environment.getActiveProfiles()` returns only the original `${ENVIRONMENT}` (dev) profile.

Comment: I don't know how you are testing this but it works for me as expected. For the sake of clarity: you can't change the active profile in your client app by editing the remote config files, but you can change the content that is loaded in the config server (I thought that's what you wanted). So if you load /my-app/dev you should see the config from `my-app-business1.yml` in the result.

Comment: @DaveSyer Thanks for answering. I don't want to change the active profile, I want to add profiles to the application with the ones defined in the Git repo so that `env.getActiveProfiles()` returns both `dev` coming from the app internal application.yml (`spring: active: profiles: dev`) and `business1` from Git myapp-dev.yaml (`spring: profiles: include: business1`). Maybe there's something wrong with my proyect. I'll start from scratch with a basic Spring Boot app to check it again and make it available in GitHub in case it doesn't work.

Comment: I just checked it again, apparently it doesn't work. I'm updating the question with more info

Comment: Once again: you can't change the active profiles with config from an external source.

Comment: Sorry I had understood that your suggestion about `spring.profiles.include` should work. Alright, right now is not supported, but wouldn't it be a nice feature to add to a future version? It would give the ability to enable specific profiles depending on the environment.

Comment: Perhaps slightly offtopic but I think it is an anti-pattern to store config in git along with the code. This is explained very well here: http://12factor.net/config

Comment: Yep, that was totally off topic. Thanks for the link though.

Comment: The selection of properties files in config server is based on the active profiles provided by the incoming app. So when you set dev as active profile, configserver will send the my-app-dev.yml. From this point of view, we are done with profile once the file is identified. Therefore, it's confusing to define again profiles in selected files. Since we can include multiple profiles on the app side, I expect configserver to provide the same number of properties files. Can you try to create my-app-dev.yml and my-app-business1.yml in git and enable both profiles on app side ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your spring-boot to 1.5.4.

I tested the same case on my Mac, I found that spring with different version behaves different.

When I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.8.RELEASE with Spring Cloud Brixton.SR7, I got the `[dev]` profile as active profile(also with Spring Boot 1.4.5.RELEASE)

When I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4.RELEASE with Spring Cloud Dalston.SR1, I got the
`[business1, dev]` profile as active profile

So I believe it is a bug in Spring Boot 1.3.x and 1.4.x

Comment: Yep, after the upgrade it is working now, thanks for letting me know!